# THREE.js Position individual instances of buffergeometry from loaded GLTF

Tags: three.js

I've adapted this example ( [link](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_instancing_scatter.html) ) to successfully load a GLTF model and instance as InstancedBufferGeometry.  How do I access and manipulate/set position for each instance? The setAttribute doesn't take effect from what I can tell, despite the posArray being populated correctly..?

Many thanks, as always!

PS: Could this be related to this issue? https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/17701

```
var loader = new GLTFLoader();
loader.load( './models/test.gltf', function ( gltf ) {

    var childObject = gltf.scene.children[0];

    modelGeometry = new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry();

    THREE.BufferGeometry.prototype.copy.call( modelGeometry, childObject.geometry );    

    let posArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++){
        posArray.push( i*5, i*5, i*5 );
    }

    modelGeometry.setAttribute("posArray", new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute( new Float32Array( posArray ), 1 )); // Not Working
    // modelGeometry.setAttribute( "posArray", new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute( new Float32Array( posArray ), 1, false, count ) ); // Also Not Working

    modelMesh = new THREE.InstancedMesh( modelGeometry, modelMaterial, count );


    init();
    animate();

} );
```

Comment: Don't mix `InstancedBufferGeometry` with `InstancedMesh`. If you use instanced geometry, then you have to modify material's shader to take in count positions from an instanced buffer attribute. If you use instanced mesh, then use `.setMatrix()` method. Just inspect/investigate carefully source code for respective examples.

Comment: Isn't that exacty as it is in the example? blossomGeometry = new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry(); -- and -- blossomMesh = new THREE.InstancedMesh( blossomGeometry, blossomMaterial, count );

Comment: Specifically for positions of instanced meshes, it's done with `.setMatrix()` method.

Comment: Finally I have achieved exactly what I wanted, and learned a lot on the way -- thank you so much for all your help.. !!

Comment: Are you willing to share your solution as an answer to your own question? This may save work for others and your future self.

Comment: Yep, will do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below is essentially what worked for me in the end.

It's an adaptation of this: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_instancing_scatter.html

*Use with caution - I don't vouch for this code by any means - I'm sure there's probably better or cleaner ways to do this. With that said my drawcalls dropped accordingly and FPS is massively increased.

**RE model size - using this method with a gltf model under 1mb I could iterate 100+ times with no significant impact. When the model size gets a few MB larger, GPU usage crept right up to 100% and eventually crashed my PC..

```
itemCount = 10;

var loader = new GLTFLoader();

var dummy = new THREE.Object3D();
loader.load( 'models/model.gltf', function ( gltf ) {

    var childObject = gltf.scene.children[0];

    geometry = new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry();

    THREE.BufferGeometry.prototype.copy.call( geometry, childObject.geometry );

    var defaultTransform = new THREE.Matrix4().multiply( new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale( 0.75, 0.75, 0.75 ) )
    geometry.applyMatrix4( defaultTransform );  

    mesh = new THREE.InstancedMesh( geometry, material, itemCount );
    mesh.instanceMatrix.setUsage( THREE.DynamicDrawUsage );

    for ( var i = 0; i < itemCount; i++ ) { // Iterate and offset x pos

        var dummyOffset = -100*i;
        dummy.position.copy( new THREE.Vector3( 0,-15, dummyOffset ) );
        dummy.updateMatrix();
        mesh.setMatrixAt( i, dummy.matrix );

    }

    mesh.instanceMatrix.needsUpdate = true;

    mesh.castShadow = true;
    mesh.receiveShadow = true;

    init(); // Run init when model has loaded..

} );
```